# How can I make the link in email clickable for Outlook without using if mso statement?

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm working on a company and my job is using SFMC for our email shootings. The clients has different devices, and **Outlook ** is a common one. Normally, we were using `<!-- if mso -->`  statement in our HTML codes for compability for Outlook, but recently we've discovered that using `<!-- if mso -->`  statement is not ideal because it's somehow breaks the utm structure. And also, we've discovered that emails that has link(s) are not clickable on whole `<a>` tag (just the text itself) on Outlook. Since we cant use `<!-- if mso -->`  statement, I've tried dozens of CSS but none of them worked perfectly for Outlook to behave like other devices.

My question is that, how can I make the `<a>` tag clickable like on other devices in the screenshots below? I'm also sharing my sample code below. Looking forward for your answers. Thank you all in advance :)

**HTML:**

```
<table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="640" style="margin: auto">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px 0 20px;background-color: #fefefe;">
          <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="30%" >
            <tr>
              <td style="font-family: Verdana, Georgia, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;height:40px;color: #fefefe;text-align: center;background-color: #6A519B;padding:0px; border-radius: 30px; font-weight: normal;">
                <a style="text-decoration:none;color: #fefefe;text-align:center;width:160px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;line-height:40px;display: inline-block;font-weight: normal;" target="_blank" href="%%=RedirectTo(@link1)=%%">
                  LEARN MORE
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

[This one is for Outlook Browsers and also for Outlook App on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AriKw.png)
[Another example for Outlook Browsers and also for Outlook App on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuc5A.png)

[Outlook App on Windows, hovered on  tag rather than text, not clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb5Uv.png)
[Outlook App on Windows, hovered on text of the  tag, clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7dwZ.png)

I've tried ChatGPT a lot. But even though I said don't give me an example with `<!-- if mso -->`, it give me every time. I can say I've tried many things for inline-css, but you can give me the same ones because I didn't save them and I don't know which one is which :(

I'm actually expecting to get an answer of YES or NO. But I'd love to hear YES and a great example.